# 4-20 mA PID controller PCB layout

Tags: pcb-design, pid-controller, 4-20ma

I have designed a 4-20 mA PID controller using an ATmega328P, an [MCP4922](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/22250A.pdf) (DAC), and an [XTR115UA](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/xtr116.pdf) (4-20 mA current loop transmitter).

I used the circuits proposed in the datasheets and the PCB and schematic files are linked.

Please have a look and give feedback on the layout or schematics; will this work or fail?

Is it helpful to use a polygon pour on both the top and bottom layers and connect one layer to Vcc and another to GND?

Here are the schematics and PCB.

This is where the 4-20 mA input signal comes in and is converted to a 0-5 V voltage with an MCP601 op-amp. The result goes to the uC:

[image]

5 V supply:

[image]

The uC output is sent to the DAC:

[image]

The DAC drives the XTR115 current loop transmitter:

[image]

The 7809 produces Vloop and the 4-20 mA output signal goes to an 180 Ω coil.

This is the layout:

[image]

Comment: Please include the schematic in the question so it will still make sense when the link dies.

Comment: Nobody with any sense is going to download those files.

Comment: Why are some of the ground symbols pointing to the sky?

Comment: Worth being specific about R1 in terms of tolerance, etc: specifying a temperature-stable, precise resistor. This is entirely responsible for converting 4-20mA to 5V. Even with calibration, if you have a resistor with a poor temperature stability your circuit will go out of calibration with tempe change.

Also, you could be disipating up to 100mW into it, and thermal resistance is of the order of 200K/W, so you can expect about 0.1% temp drift from a typical resistor ~20ppm/K, but this is stuff you need to calculate for your specified resistor and mounting if you want sensible values.

Answer (score 0):

Two things that you should consider fixing:

1. your loop should not be interrupted by LM780x as you want the current to be driven by T1 only. So LM780x input should be in parallel of T1 and then feeding the rest of the board.
2. if you want the current output to be compensated for variations of your uC is to have the GND node connected to iRet as the datasheet mentions and not

> IRET: All return current from IREG and IREF
>
> [XTR115 datasheet - FIGURE 1.](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/xtr115.pdf?ts=1591121210582)

Otherwise A1 in the block diagram cannot compensate for variations across R2 which will be coming from U3 and DAC1 in your schematics.

Comment: it seems some port names got hidden after converting the schematics to image and now new corrected schematic images was replaced. thank you @AuberonVacher for your help but I can't understand you(maybe for my poor english). "V+" port is the 12 volt input voltage that goes to 7809 input and creates the 9 volt Vloop(and this voltage is fed to pin #7 of xtr115 which accidentally has the same name V+) and as mentioned in XTR115 datasheet this Vloop voltage has to be in series by RL. Do you mean that in my loop schematic, RL and Vloop are not connected in series? –